# Изменение стилей на js на разных разрешениях экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Подключил скрипт Enquire.js. Мне необходимо, чтобы при разрешении в 600px выполнялись определенные условия по изменению стилей, а после при расширении экрана все возвращалось в исходное положение. С первым пунктом получилось, а со вторым нет - поможете? Пытаюсь сделать с помощью match-unmatch - не выходит.

Вот сам код:

```js
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 600px)", function() {
  match: function() {
    $('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("98")').css('top', '94px');
    $('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("37")').css('top', '181px');
    $('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("60")').css('top', '271px');
  },
  unmatch: function() {
    $('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("98")').css('top', '7px');
    $('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("37")').css('top', '7px');
    $('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("60")').css('top', '7px');
  }
});
```

Comment: вы уверены, что вам это надо делать на js, а не в css?

Comment: полностью! я бы с радостью, но мне уже подсказали, что на css нельзя обратиться к элементам по значению поля

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужно обращаться по значению поля? Я уверен, что если вы расскажете задачу полностью, окажется, что этот зоопарк там не нужен.

Comment: использую счетчики, каждый со своим значением которые на сайт подключаю через visual composer, который не дает установить каждому индивидуальный id. мне их нужно располагать в разных местах страницы и в зависимости от размеров экрана. с помощью скрипта  Enquire мне это сделать удалось - как можно это сделать без зоопарка? буду рад дельным советам!

Comment: Я бы отказался от такого инструмента вообще. Но, как минимум, можно эту проверку сделать яваскриптом и каждому элементу проставить айдишник/иной атрибут на основе этой проверки. Все остальное - в css, как будто и не было этой проблемы.

Comment: хочу понять: и в чем принципиальная разница? и там и там скрипт.
у меня хоть легкая библиотечка, которая даже jquery не использует

Comment: В том, что css сам будет следить за изменениями размера экрана

Comment: так по большей части ширина только раз вычисляться. а мне, чтобы показать, что сайт резиновый - нужно для демонстрации показать адекватноео отображение на разных экранах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты передаешь функцию `enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 600px)",`**`function()`**`{});`

А надо объект `enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 600px)", {});`

Что-то похожее на это

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 600px)", {
  match : function() {
    $('.test').css('height', '94px');
  },  
  unmatch : function() {
    $('.test').css('height', '194px');
  }
});
```

[Пример - меняй ширину результ таба](https://jsfiddle.net/wqn9htnv/)

Comment: Супер! спасибо!